# Is it possible to filter grouped SQL rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to group rows together but then filter each group.  So if I have the following table:

**mytable**

```
id | filename | region | text
------------------------------------
1  | aaa      | 1      | Region1 aaa
2  | bbb      | 2      | Region2 bbb
3  | aaa      | 5      | Region5 aaa
4  | bbb      | 5      | Region5 bbb
```

I want to group by filename and get out the row in each group with the `MAX` region number.  This gets the data into the appropriate groups:

```
SELECT filename
FROM mytable
GROUP BY filename
```

... but can I then pick out the entry in each group with the highest region value, which in this case would be the rows with IDs 3 and 4?  The `HAVING` clause only filters entire groups, not rows within groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number`.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from tbl
order by row_number() over(partition by filename order by region desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
from ( select * 
            , row_number() over(partition by filename order by region desc) as rn
       from table 
     ) tt 
where rn = 1
```